# Mapper: Object to Key-Values

Tags: java, mapping, datamapper, dozer

I have a domain object (DO) and Key-Value (KV) objects. How would I map each field of DO to instance of KV?

Example:

```
class DomainObject {
    String field1 = "value1";
    String field2 = "value2";
}

class KeyValue {
    String key;
    String value;
}
```

Input is DomainObject, output - two instances of KeyValue (key="field1", value="value1"; key="field2", value="value2").
P.S. I've used [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) for mapping field-to-field, but how would I do field-to-KV?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a reference of KeyValue in DomainObject therefore each KeyValue would be mapped to a item in the DomainObject's fields List.
Something simmilar to this:

```
List<KeyValue> list = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
list.add(new KeyValue("field1", "value1"));
list.add(new KeyValue("field2", "value2"));    

DomainObject domainObject = new DomainObject(list);     

class DomainObject {
    List<KeyValue> fields;

    public DomainObject(List<KeyValue> keyValueList){
        this.fields=keyValueList;
    }

    public List<KeyValue> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
}

class KeyValue {
    String key;
    String value;

    public KeyValue(String key, String value) {
        this.key=key;
        this.value=value;
    }
}
```

Or maybe you could use a hashmap for this kind of task http://tutorialswithexamples.com/java-map-and-hashmap-tutorial-with-examples/